# Difference between table access by index rowid BATCHED and table access by index rowid

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

I'm using `EXPLAIN PLAN` in an Oracle database on a simple `SELECT` statement just to find out how it works.

In one output of `EXPLAIN PLAN` there is mentioned `table access by index rowid` and in the other there is `table access by index rowid BATCHED`.

What is the difference between them?

Comment: The batched is a new 12c feature.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The documentation contains merely one sentence on this topic:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_optop.htm#GUID-4180BA97-3E2C-41F9-B282-4FB3FF9532CB

> The BATCHED access shown in Step 1 means that the database retrieves a
>   few row ids from the index, and then attempts **to access rows in block
>   order** to improve the clustering and reduce the number of times that
>   the database must access a block.

Consider a below example of the (simplified) index

```
+-------------+------------------+
| index value | block nbr-rowid  |
+-------------+------------------+
|      1      |   015-000123     |
|      2      |   034-000527     |
|      3      |   088-000285     |
|      4      |   015-000889     |
|      5      |   088-000632     |
........
........
```

---

In the "normal" (not batched) method Oracle retrieves rows in the order determined by the index:

1. retrieves block 15, then retrieves row 015-000123 from this block
2. retrieves block 34, then retrieves row 034-000527 from this block
3. retrieves block 88, then retrieves row 088-000285 from this block
4. retrieves block 15 **(again)**, then retrieves row 015-000889 from this block
5. retrieves block 88 **(again)**, then retrieves row 088-000632 from this block

---

In the batched method oracle retrieves a few entries from the index, then first sorts them by the number of block, then process entries in the order determined by number of blocks:

1. retrieves block 15, then retrieves rows 015-000123 and 015-000889 from this block
2. retrieves block 34, then retrieves row 034-000527 from this block
3. retrieves block 88, then retrieves rows 088-000285 and 088-000632 from this block

As you see in this example, blocks were fetched only 3 times instead of 5 times, so a number of block reads from the disk has been reduced - some blocks have been read only once instead of two (or more) times.

Comment: We can disable table access by index rowid batched using hint `no_batch_table_access_by_rowid`.